# SQL запрос на выборку только самых новых сообщений из всез диалогов

Tags: sql, sqlite

Предположим, что есть примерно такая таблица

```
 message       date      dialog_id

  Text1     22.09.2019       1
  Text2     23.09.2019       2
  Text3     24.09.2019       1
  Text4     25.09.2019       2
  Text5     26.09.2019       1
  Text6     27.09.2019       2
```

Как написать SQL-запрос, чтобы получить строки только с последними сообщениями для каждого диалога:

```
  Text5     26.09.2019       1
  Text6     27.09.2019       2
```

Если написать так:

```
  SELECT * FROM MESSAGES ORDER BY DATE ASC
```

то я получу просто все записи отсортированные по дате, а мне нужно только самые последние для каждого `dialog_id`, т.е `dialog_id` не должен повторяться

Comment: Укажите точно СУБД, включая версию.

Comment: @Akina обычный, родной, андроидовский SQLite

Comment: СУБД указали, хорошо. Теперь укажите версию. Ибо версии "родная для Андроида" у SQLite нет.

Comment: @Akina, ну, там от версии андроида зависит. Минимальная поддержка у меня до Android 4.4. Поэтому версия SQLite 3.7.11

Comment: Запрос из моего ответа обязан работать на этой версии. Проверяйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       FIRST_VALUE(message) OVER (PARTITION BY dialog ORDER BY DATE desc) message,
       MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY dialog) date,
       dialog
FROM sourcetable
```

Comment: Я сейчас все-таки умудрился обьяснить гуглу что мне нужно и получил ответ. SELECT message, MAX(date), dialog_id FROM messages GROUP BY dialog_id

Comment: То есть для выборки записей с максимальной (последней) датой используется MAX(date)

Comment: @СергейГрушин Полученный Вами ответ - неверный. Даже если Вы не получите сообщения типа "поле 'message' не является аргументом агрегатной функции и не входит в выражение группировки", запрос будет возвращать СЛУЧАЙНОЕ message из всех сообщений диалога. А ни разу не то, что соответствует выбранной дате. И если сегодня случайно выводится правильное message, эта лафа в любой момент может закончиться. *Я сейчас все-таки умудрился обьяснить гуглу что мне нужно* Правильный запрос должен был звучать типа "выбрать первую запись в группе".

Comment: ok, но придется проверить попозже, пока не разберусь с тем, что такое DISTINCT и другие незнакомые мне операторы, так как на деле таблица обширнее, чем я обрисовал в вопросе. пока что оставил запрос как есть, а приведение данных к нужному виду выполняю уже в  java-коде.

Comment: я обязательно проверю попозже на более простой версии таблицы и отпишусь/отмечу

Answer (score -1):

Используйте группировку

```
SELECT
  *
FROM (SELECT
  *
FROM messages
ORDER BY date ASC) AS x
GROUP BY dialog_id
)
```